# Skype installation

Tags: skype

I tried to install skype following many of the commands shown in the sloution page of askubuntu for "how to install skype". But finally the output is coming: E: Package 'skype:i386' has no installation candidate.
Please help ASAP.

Comment: skype for linux is 64-bit only now

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 16.04 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are installing from a ppa or external source that still has the 32bit package. That will probably not log in anyway because it is not supported anymore. Please provide some information:

```
apt-cache policy skype*
```

besides that you can download the [64bit deb package directly from skype.com](https://www.skype.com/de/get-skype/) and use dpkg from a terminal to install it.

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/skypeforlinux-64.deb
```

Comment: skype-common:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
skype-bin:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
     4.3.0.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: skype-call-recorder:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.11-1~getdeb2~wily
  Version table:
     0.11-1~getdeb2~wily 500
        500 http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps amd64 Packages
skype:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
skype4pidgin:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
skype-mid:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:

Comment: @Ani What are you trying to tell with these system messages? Please add all the details to your question and format it properly (as code).

Comment: This is what I got in the terminal when I ran the command  apt-cache policy skype*

Comment: skype:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
I obtained this by running the command  apt-cache policy skype

Comment: @Ani Once again: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/999351/edit) and add all details there!

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install skype
```

Option 2:

- [Download Skype](https://www.skype.com/en/get-skype/). For Ubuntu you should download `.deb`.
- Open it with GDebi package installer.
- Install the package.

This should solve your problem.